# how do I make relationships for 4 tables including pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have many to many relationships. Imagine I have 3 tables. Something like this :

users.

roles.

role_user.

(This example is also provided in laravel's docs).

Now I'm doing this : `$user->roles()` which returns roles with Pivot attributes . but what I actually want to do is move forward and also get the appropriate data from the 4th table. something like this `$user->roles()->types();` and the difficult thing is that this types() belongs to pivot table.

Do you know how to do this kind of thing ? where Do I write `types()` function?

Comment: how is type related to roles? is type an attribute or a table? If type is a table, how is it related to roles? Give me an example of the relation between type and roles. is there a belongs to or has many roles ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "Roles" model has the relationship set you may try

`$user->roles()->with("types")`

Source docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading